# What's the proper way to deal with Js.Nullable?

Tags: nullable, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```rust
let str_result: Js.Nullable.t(string) = Js.Nullable.return("something");
let int_result: Js.Nullable.t(int) = Js.Nullable.fromOption(Some(5));
Js.log([|str_result, int_result|]);
```

But of course, I get the following complaint:

```
Error: This expression has type Js.Nullable.t(int) = Js.nullable(int)
       but an expression was expected of type
         Js.Nullable.t(string) = Js.nullable(string)
       Type int is not compatible with type string
```

So I use `string_of_int`:

```rust
Js.log([|str_result, string_of_int|]);
```

But I then run into the problem of:

```
This has type:
  Js.Nullable.t(int) (defined as Js.nullable(int))
But somewhere wanted:
  int
```

Is the proper way to use a `switch` or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the "inner" type of a `Js.Nullable.t` using `Js.Nullable.bind`:

```rust
let str_of_int_result: Js.Nullable.t(string) =
  Js.Nullable.bind(int_result, (. n) => string_iof_int(n));
```

Alternatively, you can turn a `Js.Nullable.t` into an `option`, pattern match on it, and then optionally wrap it up in a `Js.Nullable.t` again:

```rust
let str_of_int_result: Js.Nullable.t(string) =
  switch (Js.Nullable.toOption(int_result)) {
  | Some(n) => Js.Nullable.return(string_of_int(n)))
  | None    => Js.Nullable.null
  };
```

These are equivalent, for the sake of comparison. You'll usually want to use the first method if you want to keep it a `Js.Nullable.t`, and the second method if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

When using a ReasonReact Ref to access a DOM node, I'm using the following to access the DOM node as an object (aka `Js.t<'a>`).

```
let nodeRef = React.useRef(Js.Nullable.null)

...

switch Js.Nullable.toOption(nodeRef.current) {
| None => ()
| Some(node) => {
    let node = ReactDOMRe.domElementToObj(node)
    node["scrollTop"] = node["scrollHeight"]
  }
}

...

<main ref={ReactDOM.Ref.domRef(nodeRef)}>
```